# Is the force at the origin of electromagnetic fields infinite?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electrons, charge, point-particles

We know that the electromagnetic force created by its field from an charged particle, e.g. a electron gets weaker at larger and larger distances from that electron. Electrons are treated as points with no size or boundry, so all that exist is an electromagnetic field that starts from an point (the electron) and radiate outwards. Since points are infinitely small you can go closer and closer to that electron and feel an ever increasing force. So the question is if the electromagnetic field gets infinitely strong at its point of origin and if not, whats the maximal force that can be expected from an electron or other charged particle.

Comment: Are you interested in the force that an electron exerts on another or are you going for the case "Doesn't that means the electron exerts infinite force on itself"? The answers to each of the questions are quite different (the self-force issue will lead you to [radiation reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the force does get infinite at zero distance. In classical electrodynamics, where particles are just single points, though, the probability of them intersecting is zero, because each particle is just a single point in space. So the probability of having initial conditions that are "just right" for two particles to occupy the same position is
$$\frac{\text{finite number}}{\text{infinite possible initial conditions}} = 0$$

In quantum electrodynamics, this same issue is linked to infinities in the theory that have to be "renormalized".

Answer (score 0):

An infinite field is different from an infinite force. To get a force, you need a second charge on which the field can act. With any finite amount of work, you can only bring the second charge in to some finite distance.

The infinite field is, however, a problem because the field has an energy density associated with it. If you do the integral, the total energy of a point charge is divergent. Relativistically, this implies that an electron should have infinite mass ($E=mc^2$), which is not the case.

Divergences like this are usually interpreted as signs that the theory you're working with breaks down and is no longer able to make predictions. You need a better theory. There are two different theories that extend classical electromagnetism: quantum mechanics and general relativity. Both of them modify classical electromagnetism's description of what happens close to a point charge. We don't currently know how to reconcile them with each other, but for current high-energy physics experiments, the quantum description works.

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is if the electromagnetic field gets infinitely strong at its point of origin and if not, whats the maximal force that can be expected from an electron or other charged particle.

The interaction energy of two "electrons" (I put electrons in quotes since I treat them classically here) located at $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$ is:
$$
U = \frac{ke^2}{|\vec r_1 - \vec r_2|}\;,
$$

Classically, the force on one due to the other is
$$
\vec F = \frac{ke^2(\vec r_1 - \vec r_2)}{|\vec r_1 - \vec r_2|^3}
$$

Both the interaction energy and the force tend towards infinity as the "electrons" approach each other.

An electron can not be treated classically in most situations, but supposing we can treat it classically, we could say that the force gets infinitely strong, at least formally.

Of course, in practice, you can never measure an infinite force for a variety of reasons, most obviously because you can not buy a force meter that goes up to "infinity."

Even in principle, you are usually not concerned about this sort of thing. In most cases you have a particular situation in mind. E.g., a quantum electron in the field of a classical point charge (like in the hydrogen atom). In this quantum case you don't encounter infinite forces since the electrons are quantized into orbitals.